# jQuery Dropdown Check List: jQuery click() anomaly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with several dropdownchecklists, all with checkboxes (multiple selects possible). Inside document ready, I have this simple code:

```
$(":checkbox").click(alert('TEST'));
```

The problem is that when the page first loads, the alert fires.  What I want to do is only fire the alert when one of the dropdownchecklist boxes is clicked.  I know I am being dull of wit here.  Can someone enlighten me?

Another way to state the problem is simply "How can I activate a function when a dropdownchecklist checkbox is clicked?"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

$(":checkbox").click(function(){alert('TEST');});

Comment: David, Thank you for the fast response! That of course made the thing stop firing on page load (man was I being dumb LOL thanks).  However, the alert does not fire when the dropdownchecklist checkbox is clicked.  Tried giving one of the checkboxes a specific class and then doing this:

$(".specific_class").click(function(){alert('TEST');});

and even that doesn't work.  Apparently I need a different selector?

Comment: Where is this click binding code? It could be happening before the browser has actually rendered the checkbox list, thus doesnt match anything "YET!" Make sure to put this in $(document).ready(function() { $(":checkbox").click(function(){alert('TEST');}); }); and if you already have document.ready code, make sure its after whatever renders the checkboxlist

Comment: You were correct, I had the statement in the wrong place.  However, I ALSO noticed (via Firebug)that the dropdownchecklist plugin wraps each select option in a div with class "ui-dropdownchecklist-item".  So I can get the whole div by selecting that class or the children of the div by $('.ui-dropdownchecklist-item').children(). Thx!

One other detail I notice: my checkboxes have a label.  Clicking to the right of the label is clicking the parent, not the children.  So now all I have to do is call my function for both the .ui-dropdownchecklist-item class and its children.  Thanks for the help!